# How to provide security to Hadoop http UI?

Tags: security, hadoop, kerberos, hadoop2

I tried to provide security via kerberos but getting error while starting datanode. So I thought to check another option. I see found the following information in the document.
`hadoop.http.authentication.type: Defines authentication used for the HTTP web-consoles. The supported values are: simple | kerberos | #AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_CLASSNAME#. The dfeault value is simple.`

What is `AUTHENTICATION_HANDLER_CLASSNAME`. And how can I implement this.

Comment: This question is too broad.

Comment: @John R Smith, I am failing to add authentication. Do you have any documentation regarding this.